# Fill image are based on coordinates in cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I am stuck on this easy task, I have a rectangular area in an image that I need to fill with a color. I know the x1, x2, y1, y2 coordinate of the image how to fill the area based on coordinate? consider the below image and the coordinates of the area that I want to fill with a is x1 = 132.5, x2 = 270, y1 = 68.5, y2 = 141. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Get the center of your rectangle area (or any point inside the rectangle) and use cv2.floodFill().

Comment: welcome. what have you tried? [ask], [mre]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Explanation**

To achieve what you want, you can use the *cv2.rectangle* function and set the last parameter to -1 to fill up the rectangle region with your defined color pixel.

*Note: Please don't use the loop/iteration approach to fill the pixels if performance is matter.

```
import cv2

# Load an image from file (Replace with your image path)
image = cv2.imread('sample.png')

x1 = 132.5  # Replace with your X1 coordinate
y1 = 270    # Replace with your Y1 coordinate
x2 = 68.5   # Replace with your X2 coordinate
y2 = 141    # Replace with your Y2 coordinate

# Define the new RGB values (0-255) for the pixel
red = 255
green = 0
blue = 0

# Change the pixel value at the specified coordinates
image_new = cv2.rectangle(image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(blue,green,red),-1)
# Save the modified image
cv2.imwrite('output.png', image_new)
```

Comment: Awesome, Thanks it worked as expected

Comment: Hi, Please accept my answer if this helped you